# Does Not Exist using Multiple Columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to find all records in my #TempTable that are not in the staging table. 
Its important to note that the comparison needs to take place over 16 fields.

I have tried several combinations and nothing seems to work.

```
    SELECT CustomerAccountNo FROM #TempTable        
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT e.[CustomerAccountNo] ,
    e.[MeterNo] ,
    e.[CustomerName1] ,
    e.[ServiceAddress1] ,
    e.[ServiceAddress2] ,
    e.[ServiceCity] ,
    e.[ServiceState] ,
    e.[ServiceZip] ,
    e.[BillingAddress1] ,
    e.[BillingAddress2] ,
    e.[BillingAddress3] ,
    e.[BillingCity] ,
    e.[BillingState] ,
    e.[BillingZip] ,
    e.[BillingZip4] ,
    e.[PrimaryPhoneNumber] FROM #TempTable e
    JOIN dbo.Staging s
    ON e.CustomerAccountNo = s.CustomerAccountNo AND
    e.MeterNo = s.MeterNo AND
    e.CustomerName1 = s.CustomerName1 AND
    e.ServiceAddress1 = s.ServiceAddress1 AND
    e.ServiceAddress2 = s.ServiceAddress2 AND
    e.ServiceCity = s.ServiceCity AND
    e.ServiceState = s.ServiceState AND
    e.ServiceZip = s.ServiceZip AND
    e.BillingAddress1 = s.BillingAddress1 AND
    e.BillingAddress2 = s.BillingAddress2 AND
    e.BillingAddress3 = s.BillingAddress3 AND
    e.BillingCity = s.BillingCity AND
    e.BillingState = s.BillingState AND
    e.BillingZip = s.BillingZip AND
    e.BillingZip4 = s.BillingZip4 AND
    e.PrimaryPhoneNumber= s.PrimaryPhoneNumber          
    )
```

Comment: How does it not work? Are you getting too many records? Not enough? Or...?

Comment: In this code combination, I get all records back. Like if everything is missing. In others I get nothing back...

Comment: @HABO - they are there I see them `FROM #TempTable e
    JOIN dbo.Staging s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `JOIN`, try using [Except.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
SELECT CustomerAccountNo, MeterNo -- and so on
FROM #TempTable
EXCEPT
SELECT CustomerAccountNo, MeterNo -- and so on
FROM Staging
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a join and look for null.  Like this

```
SELECT e.*
 FROM #TempTable e
 LEFT JOIN dbo.Staging s
    ON e.CustomerAccountNo = s.CustomerAccountNo AND
    e.MeterNo = s.MeterNo AND
    e.CustomerName1 = s.CustomerName1 AND
    e.ServiceAddress1 = s.ServiceAddress1 AND
    e.ServiceAddress2 = s.ServiceAddress2 AND
    e.ServiceCity = s.ServiceCity AND
    e.ServiceState = s.ServiceState AND
    e.ServiceZip = s.ServiceZip AND
    e.BillingAddress1 = s.BillingAddress1 AND
    e.BillingAddress2 = s.BillingAddress2 AND
    e.BillingAddress3 = s.BillingAddress3 AND
    e.BillingCity = s.BillingCity AND
    e.BillingState = s.BillingState AND
    e.BillingZip = s.BillingZip AND
    e.BillingZip4 = s.BillingZip4 AND
    e.PrimaryPhoneNumber= s.PrimaryPhoneNumb
    WHERE s.CustomerAccountNo is null
```

Comment: It needs to be an `OUTER` join. Otherwise how can the ON clause ever work?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yep, I left out the `left`.  (If you have to left something left is it, I guess.)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more detailed circumstance to get correct answer.

Clearly, you don't have any connection between your FROM clause and WHERE clause so the query will return all.

Try this one:

```
SELECT CustomerAccountNo FROM #TempTable t       
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Staging s WHERE
    t.CustomerAccountNo = s.CustomerAccountNo AND
    t.MeterNo = s.MeterNo AND
    t.CustomerName1 = s.CustomerName1 AND
    t.ServiceAddress1 = s.ServiceAddress1 AND
    t.ServiceAddress2 = s.ServiceAddress2 AND
    t.ServiceCity = s.ServiceCity AND
    t.ServiceState = s.ServiceState AND
    t.ServiceZip = s.ServiceZip AND
    t.BillingAddress1 = s.BillingAddress1 AND
    t.BillingAddress2 = s.BillingAddress2 AND
    t.BillingAddress3 = s.BillingAddress3 AND
    t.BillingCity = s.BillingCity AND
    t.BillingState = s.BillingState AND
    t.BillingZip = s.BillingZip AND
    t.BillingZip4 = s.BillingZip4 AND
    t.PrimaryPhoneNumber= s.PrimaryPhoneNumber          
    )
```

Comment: The where clause only takes in consideration 1 of the 16 fields.
I need to make sure all 16 fields are "NOT IN"